# Connect Websocket with Poco libraries

Tags: c++, connection, websocket, poco-libraries

I am trying to connect to the [Echo Test Websocket](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) using the [Poco](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html) C++ libraries.
In order to do so here is my code which should set up the Websocket:

```
HTTPClientSession cs("echo.websocket.org");
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/ws");
HTTPResponse response;

WebSocket* m_psock = new WebSocket(cs, request, response);
m_psock->close(); //close immidiately
```

However it does not work:
I am getting an error message like this:

```
Poco::Exception: WebSocket Exception: Cannot upgrade to WebSocket connection: Not Found
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I would ask that on the [Poco forum](http://pocoproject.org/forum/)

Comment: I did that, but there's no help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Not Found' error is the standard HTTP 404 Not Found returned by the HTTP server. It generally means the resource you are requesting does not exist.

I got your code to work by changing the resource from `"/ws"` to `"/"`:

```
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/");
```

and adding the following line

```
request.set("origin", "http://www.websocket.org");
```

before creating the new `WebSocket`. I think it's a header pair that many (or all?) WebSocket servers expect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a reply from the echo server you must also make sure to use a Http 1.1 request.  Poco defaults to Http 1.0.

```
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/",HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

This is a complete example,

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h"
#include "Poco/Net/WebSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include <iostream>

using Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequest;
using Poco::Net::HTTPResponse;
using Poco::Net::HTTPMessage;
using Poco::Net::WebSocket;


int main(int args,char **argv)
{
    HTTPClientSession cs("echo.websocket.org",80);    
    HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text",HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    request.set("origin", "http://www.websocket.org");
    HTTPResponse response;


    try {

        WebSocket* m_psock = new WebSocket(cs, request, response);
        char *testStr="Hello echo websocket!";
        char receiveBuff[256];

        int len=m_psock->sendFrame(testStr,strlen(testStr),WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
        std::cout << "Sent bytes " << len << std::endl;
        int flags=0;

        int rlen=m_psock->receiveFrame(receiveBuff,256,flags);
        std::cout << "Received bytes " << rlen << std::endl;
        std::cout << receiveBuff << std::endl;

        m_psock->close();

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complete example for a 'wss' (i.e. secure) connection.

```
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/Net/AcceptCertificateHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/Context.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SSLManager.h"
#include "Poco/Net/Websocket.h"
#include "Poco/SharedPtr.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"

int main(int args, char **argv) {
  Poco::URI uri("wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw");

  Poco::Net::initializeSSL();

  Poco::Net::Context::Params params;
  params.verificationMode = Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE;
  params.verificationDepth = 9;
  params.loadDefaultCAs = true;
  params.cipherList = "ALL";

  Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE, params);

  // This accepts all certificates. Even invalid ones.
  // Use for testing only.
  Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(false);

  Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(NULL, ptrCert, context);

  auto port = uri.getPort();
  auto host = uri.getHost();
  Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession httpSession(host, port);

  auto path = uri.getPath();
  Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
  request.set("origin", "http://ws.postman-echo.com/raw");
  Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;

  try {
    Poco::Net::WebSocket m_psock(httpSession, request, response);
    std::string testStr = "Hello echo websocket!";
    char receiveBuff[256];

    int len = m_psock.sendFrame(testStr.c_str(), testStr.length(), Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
    std::cout << "Sent message " << testStr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sent bytes " << len << std::endl;
    int flags = 0;

    int rlen = m_psock.receiveFrame(receiveBuff, 256, flags);
    std::cout << "Recv bytes " << rlen << std::endl;
    std::string received(receiveBuff, rlen);
    std::cout << "Recv message " << received << std::endl;

    m_psock.close();

  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the code of Olof and Jason.
Setting the origin of the request is (no longer?) necessary.

##### Compiles with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -o websocket-poco websocket-poco.cpp  -lPocoRedis -lPocoUtil -lPocoNet -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoCrypto -lPocoXML -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation
```

##### Requires

```
sudo apt install libpoco-dev
```

##### Result

```
Hello initially!        (Request served by 7811941c69e658)
Hello again!
And again!
```

Save to `websocket-poco.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Net/AcceptCertificateHandler.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/WebSocket.h>

using Poco::Net::HTTPMessage;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequest;
using Poco::Net::HTTPResponse;
using Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession;
using Poco::Net::WebSocket;
using std::cout;
using std::string;


WebSocket open(string host, string path){
    HTTPSClientSession  session (host);
    HTTPRequest         request (HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    HTTPResponse        response;
    return WebSocket (session, request, response);
}


string receiveFrame (WebSocket websocket) {
    int   FRAME_OP_CONT = WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CONT;
    int   max_size = 1024;
    char  frame_buffer[max_size];
    int   actual_size = websocket.receiveFrame(frame_buffer, max_size, FRAME_OP_CONT);
    return string (frame_buffer, actual_size);
}


string echo (WebSocket websocket, string text, bool initial_request = false) {
    string initial_response, response;
    websocket.sendFrame (text.c_str(), text.length(), WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
    if (initial_request) {
      initial_response  = receiveFrame(websocket);
    }
    response            = receiveFrame(websocket);
    if (initial_request) {
      response += "        (" + initial_response + ")";
    }
    return response;
}


int main() {
    auto websocket  = open("echo.websocket.org", "/");
    auto response_1 = echo(websocket, "Hello initially!", true);
    auto response_2 = echo(websocket, "Hello again!");
    auto response_3 = echo(websocket, "And again!");
    websocket.close();

    cout <<  response_1 << "\n";
    cout <<  response_2 << "\n";
    cout <<  response_3 << "\n";
}
```