# Websocket broadcasting not working

Tags: c++, websocket, poco, server, broadcast

I have an issue with my websocket.
I have recently switched my server from PHP to c++ side, and used the POCO library, i used exactly this script:
[WebSocketServer.cpp](https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop/blob/master/third_party/poco/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp)

For the one client side in c++ i used a snipet i found here on stackoverflow:
[WebSocketClient.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26932188/3913496)

I modified the client a bit, first it sends a default message as soon as i connect to the server.

I wrapped the whole thing with an Update function from my main app, that I am constantly able to recieve messages:

```
void CLeagueStats :: Update( ) {
        if(m_Connected) {
                string msg = Recv( );
                if(msg != "") {
                        //handleIncomingMsg( msg );
                }
        } else if(GetTime() - LastReconnectTime > 90 || LastReconnectTime == 0) {
                Connect( );
        }
}

string CLeagueStats :: Recv( ) {
        char receiveBuff[256];
        int flags=0;

        int rlen=m_psock->receiveFrame(receiveBuff,256,flags);
        CONSOLE_Print("Recv: "+string(receiveBuff));
        return string(receiveBuff);

}
```

I have now written a totally simple javascript client which is initalizing on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ip_port = 'localhost:9980';
var ohc;

if (typeof (MozWebSocket) == 'function')
        ohc = new MozWebSocket('ws://' + ip_port);
else
        ohc = new WebSocket('ws://' + ip_port);

var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
self.ohc.send("hey");
}, 500);
</script>
```

The server log includes both messages:

> **C++ App:**
>    WebSocket connection established. Frame received (length=5, flags=0x81).
>
> **Javascript:** 
>   WebSocket connection established. Frame received (length=3, flags=0x81).

But the log from the C++ App does send the connection message and recieve it back, but i dont get the message from the js-client:

```
[Websocket] Connecting to websocket.
[Websocket] Send: hello
[Websocket] Recv: hello
```

Why this happen?
Isn't the snippet form the servercode directly sending the message back to all clients?

```
n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
app.logger().information(Poco::format("Frame received (length=%d, flags=0x%x).", n,unsigned(flags)));
ws.sendFrame(buffer, n, flags);
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a situation to reproduce the environment but I had a similar issue using Python and IOS web sockets. Every other technology we used was working in with Python Sockets flawlessly but IOS web socket had problem. After many days later we find out that IOS web socket does not send a communication ender (EOM) that Python can process. So the we had to handle different IOS sockets different.

I have checked WebSocket flags 81 so it is text and frame is finish. But I would suggest you to check from Developer Tools of browser to see what is recieved over the socket connection from Network Tab.

I may be problem of End of Message did not understood by javascript WebSocket. If you see the data hello on developer tools then it would be easy to handle with situation. However if you don't see any message coming then the problem is most probably from C++ code.

In attachment you can see how Chrome shows the socket data transactions. Keep in mind that clicking on the connection on the left list will update the transactions they are not live.

Hope this helps you.[image]

If not go deeper using tcpdump or similar sowftware to be sure if they really sent and got by two sides.

Comment: I used to use that dev tool. The C++ server send this already directly back, so i got an answere. However not to the C++ Client...

Comment: For C++ client try tcpdump