# Websocket connection with Poco libraries

Tags: c++, websocket, connection, poco-libraries

I have a problem with websocket connection to wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime.

I found an axample in this question: [Connect Websocket with Poco libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532388/connect-websocket-with-poco-libraries) , but I can't do the same with my wss:// address.

```
HTTPClientSession cs("wss://www.bitmex.com", 443);
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_CONNECT, "/realtime", HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request.set("origin", "wss://www.bitmex.com");
HTTPResponse response;

try {

    WebSocket* m_psock = new WebSocket(cs, request, response);
    //some code
}
catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
}
```

I'm always receiving the exception: "Host not found" after string

WebSocket* m_psock = new WebSocket(cs, request, response);

Comment: Did you try the complete solution presented in the answer you linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532388/connect-websocket-with-poco-libraries).  For example, I note your use of set "origin" is different to the code in the linked solution.

Comment: Yes, I did it. My problem is the wss (SSL connection). I can't find any example with poco websockets + SSL

Comment: I would try to rework that example, with aim of replacing `HTTPClientSession` with `HTTPSClientSession`

Comment: Try looking at the test code that comes with Poco for examples.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPClientSession` takes a host string as the first param but you have given a host string with a protocol on the front.

The samples have a `WebSocketServer` in `Net` but sometimes you need to look at the test suite to find more details and it does require a little more work.

See [WebSocketTest.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/3fc3e5f5b8462f7666952b43381383a79b8b5d92/Net/testsuite/src/WebSocketTest.cpp#L124) for a basic test that uses a [WebSocket](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html).